# Getting angular-masonry to work it says it has no method 'imagesLoaded'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-masonry

I am trying to get [angular-masonry](http://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/) by passy to work with an infinite scroll directive, but I am having some problems.  I am doing it in a plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/coe79LeyCoO137ntdb2a?p=preview). It says in the console as an error, TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'.

Here's my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="masonry@*" data-semver="2.1.0-7" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/2.1.07/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="imagesloaded@*" data-semver="v3.0.2" src="http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="angular-masonry.js"></script>
    <script src="myApp.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div masonry="">
      <img class="repeated-img masonry-brick" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="http://placehold.it/225x{{image.height}}/{{image.color.bg}}/{{image.color.text}}&text={{image.num}}" />
    </div>
    <div scroll-trigger="loadMore()" threshold="100">Trigger element</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and my infinite scroll directive and app module

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['wu.masonry']);
myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [
    {num: 1, height:400}, {num: 2, height:250}, 
    {num: 3, height:225}, {num: 4, height:200}, 
    {num: 5, height:200}, {num: 6, height:225}, 
    {num: 7, height:300}, {num: 8, height:250}, 
    {num: 9, height:275}, {num: 10, height:350}, 
    {num: 11, height:450}, {num: 12, height:275}, 
    {num: 13, height:225}, {num: 14, height:250}, 
    {num: 15, height:250}, {num: 16, height:225}]

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var last = $scope.images[$scope.images.length - 1].num;
    var heights = [200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 350, 400, 450]
    var colors = ["859994", "51C0C4", "C3D9C6", "EBE2C7", "F5E6D3"]
    var textColor = "ffffff";
    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
      var randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
      $scope.images.push({num: last + i, height: (heights[Math.floor(Math.random()*heights.length)]), color: {bg: randColor, text: textColor}});
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('scrollTrigger', function($window) {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var offset = parseInt(attrs.threshold) || 0;
            var e = jQuery(element[0]);
            var doc = jQuery(document);
            angular.element(document).bind('scroll', function() {
                if (doc.scrollTop() + $window.innerHeight + offset > e.offset().top) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.scrollTrigger);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks and sorry but I'm new to angular.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should load jQuery before angular, also I used newer version of masonry (3.1.2) because it seems that imagesloaded is dependent on a newer version:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="//desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
```

---

From [angular.element(jqLite) docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

Here is the source code(https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.13/src/Angular.js#L1257):

```
function bindJQuery() {
  // bind to jQuery if present;
  jQuery = window.jQuery;
  // reset to jQuery or default to us.
  if (jQuery) {
    jqLite = jQuery;
    extend(jQuery.fn, {
      scope: JQLitePrototype.scope,
      isolateScope: JQLitePrototype.isolateScope,
      controller: JQLitePrototype.controller,
      injector: JQLitePrototype.injector,
      inheritedData: JQLitePrototype.inheritedData
    });
    // Method signature:
    //     jqLitePatchJQueryRemove(name, dispatchThis, filterElems, getterIfNoArguments)
    jqLitePatchJQueryRemove('remove', true, true, false);
    jqLitePatchJQueryRemove('empty', false, false, false);
    jqLitePatchJQueryRemove('html', false, false, true);
  } else {
    jqLite = JQLite;
  }
  angular.element = jqLite;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this worked perfectly. One question though why jQuery before angular.  Angular isn't dependent on jQuery right?

Comment: I updated my answer. Angular is not dependent on jqeury , but jqLite can be overriden by jQuery and when you work with jQuery plugins you probably need that.

Comment: awesome I was working on getting this same example with angular-isotope as well as doing it with angular-masonty and I moved the angular below the jQuery and that one worked fine too.  That makes sense now why that works.  Hey thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, think the angular masonry project should more clearly list the dependencies, as it just says to load the js file but doesn't have the info about including masonry itself or jQuery